# Why can't Crystal infer this type in initializer?

Tags: crystal-lang

I have the following code:

```
class Triangle
  def initialize(@sides : Array(Int32))
    @set = Set.new(@sides)
  end
end
```

However I get a compiler error that gives me:

```
Can't use Set(T) as the type of instance variable @set of Triangle, use a more specific type
```

I would have thought since `@sides` is of type `Array(Int32)` that there would be type inference on the set.  I've read through [the docs](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/type_inference.html) but not seeing an answer in there.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, type inference for instance variables is not smart enough to figure out that generic type. I guess it should be possible and will probably be implemented some time, but for now you'll have to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the set's type, like this:

```
class Triangle
  def initialize(@sides : Array(Int32))
    @set = Set(Int32).new(@sides)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew how to do it but didn't understand why the compiler needed it (that was my question).